# Finding the Name of a Range using VBA

Tags: named-ranges

Using VBA, how do you find the name of the range of an active cell (merged cells)? I have a worksheet that I have established a few named ranges. i.e. K7:R28 is a range of merged cells and is named "LocM11". I typed that into the Name box and it is already established. In my VBA code, if a user clicks on the merged cells of K7:R28 and presses a command button I want the code to return the name "LocM11" and save it as a variable to be used later in the code. I've looked everywhere but this has me stumped. Any advice is appreciated.

I've tried some code sniplets I found on the internet to no avail. I've found code that uses VBA to name a range, but I do not want to do that. I have the name established. I want to know the already existing Name and save it as a variable.

Comment: check in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.range#example

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Dim activeRange As Range
Dim rangeName As String

Set activeRange = ActiveCell.Range
rangeName = Application.Range(activeRange.Address).Name

Debug.Print rangeName
```

More details - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.range#example